# Keep track of job applications sent outside Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Stack Overflow Careers keeps track of my sent applications in `Messages -> Sent -> Applications`.

However, even when advertising on Careers, many employers use private platforms to accept applications.

It would be nice if I could manually annotate all my applications right inside Careers, in order to keep track of all of them in one place.

Comment: I don't think this is technically possible unless you mean adding it as pure text somewhere?

Comment: I suppose this would require moving Applications menu out of the messaging utility, and giving the user the ability to manually insert some metadata in preformatted fields (e.g. date, name of the employer (possibly linked with their page on Careers), material sent to them and so on).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're talking about this internally already. Nothing is imminent, but we're really going to be focusing on improving the job searching and application experience for developers this next year. So get ready! ;)

Being able to quickly see which jobs you've applied to (without having to dig into messaging) is on the list of things we're talking about to help make Careers better.